# Spring Boot + Jetty + TLS1.2 (HTTPS)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, https, jetty

I have an application running locally with Spring Boot and Jetty. The problem comes when I try to add TLS1.2 to my project to support HTTPS. I work perfectly with http but now I want the services to be published in https with TLS1.2. And here is when I fail and I get errors.

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverProperties': Could not bind properties; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ssl[keyAlias]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'ssl[keyAlias]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'ssl[keyAlias]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]: Bean property 'ssl[keyAlias]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:130)
at com.viajesurbis.Application.main(Application.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>springboot-jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>springboot-jersey</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <jersey.version>2.8</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is my main where I start my application:

```
        package com.viajesurbis;

import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.viajesurbis.config.JerseyConfig;
import com.viajesurbis.rest.RestResource;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { RestResource.class })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).showBanner(false).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/rest/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties file: (This file is located in the src/main/resources path of my project)

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: #REMOVED#
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: jetty
```

I also have the file called keystore.p12 in the path src / main / resources and just in case I have also put the keystrore.p12 in the project, where the pom.xml is located. That is, I have the file duplicated but it still does not work.

If I delete the content of the application.properties then the application works perfectly for me but in HTTP and I want it to work in HTTPS.

Many thanks for your help.
Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ssl configuration support has only been added to version 1.1.7:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I just upgraded spring-boot-starter-parent version to 1.1.0.RELEASE and it got rid of the error:

Try to use this parent in your pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Hello tsolakp, many thanks for your help but I get a error:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]:
You can add this to my pom.xml and can you tell me how this file would look?

Comment: Please, can any user help me? Thanks.

Comment: @Javi. I am not sure if you still struggling with this issue. If you do try my updated answer to your question.

Comment: Hello @tsolakp, many thanks for your help but I continue with errors and this still does not work. Please, can you create a new project with all my files and java classes? This way you will see the errors that I have.

Comment: I did exactly that. Copied your pom and application code and build/run the app without any errors.